# Can I capture the returned value of a routine used in RUN-MAIN?

Tags: program-entry-point, subroutine, raku

I want a script to run a subroutine exported from a module, with the exported sub to be run as MAIN in the script. The subroutine does all that I want, except that it returns the result instead of printing it.

RUN-MAIN *seems* to achieve most of what I'm aiming for, but I'm not sure how to grab the returned value of the routine.

Is there a way I can capture the output of the routine given to RUN-MAIN to be printed? Is RUN-MAIN the right approach for this sort of thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redispatch can be used within a wrapped routine to call the original. `say` can then be used on the result of the redispatch within the wrap. This will also generate usage from the original routine.

```
sub foo (
  $input #= The data we want
) {
  return $input;
}

&foo.wrap( sub (|) { callsame.say } );

RUN-MAIN &foo, Nil;
```

`$ raku filename.raku`

```
Usage:
  filename.raku <input>
  
    <input>    The data we want
```

Answer (score 5):

You could use the function composition operator [`infix:<∘>`](https://docs.perl6.org/language/operators#infix_%E2%88%98) or `infix:<o>`

```
sub foo ($name, Int $n=1) { 
    "Hello $name\n" xx $n 
}; 
RUN-MAIN &say o &foo, Nil; #or &foo Ro &say
```

but unfortunately, it is changing the signature

```
sub foo ($name, Int $n=1) { 
    "Hello $name\n" xx $n 
};

say &foo.signature;
say (&foo Ro &say).signature;
```

so default `USAGE` message does not work.

Comment: The lack of USAGE is indeed unfortunate, but infix:<∘> is a nice idea! I'll have a play around with it.

Comment: I'm playing around with the following which seems to doing what I want so far:
    our &MAIN = &say ∘ &foo;
    RUN-MAIN( &foo, Nil );

Answer (score 2):

The following seems to accomplish what I intended (where `foo` is the target sub).

```
RUN-MAIN( &foo, Nil );

sub MAIN ( |c --> Nil ) {
  foo(|c).say;
}
```

EDIT: Unfortunately this solution is not ideal, as it runs &foo twice.

Comment: It is not a typo. The first `|c` is a Capture parameter, and the additional prepended `|` is to make it a Slip. This didn't quite work as I'd expected, although I'll need to remind myself why, and if it was exactly this or something else that caused my issue (IIRC I was running MAIN twice somehow, once with and once without `say`). After playing around a bit this was the final result I came up with: https://github.com/manwar/perlweeklychallenge-club/blob/master/challenge-035/daniel-mita/perl6/ch-1.p6

Comment: It seems I misunderstood the documentation, so yes the extra pipe is in fact a typo :)