# Optimize without sacrificing usual workflow: arguments, POD etc

Tags: optimization, command-line-arguments, program-entry-point, raku, precompile

https://martimm.github.io/gnome-gtk3/content-docs/tutorial/Application/sceleton.html , abbreviated:

> In Raku, it is important that the main program is kept small. This is because all code, program and modules are parsed and compiled into an intermediate code which will be executed by a virtual machine. Most of the time that will be MoarVM but there is also a JVM and later possibly others. Anyways, before running, the compiled modules are saved into .precomp directories but not the program. This means that the program always get parsed and compiled before running and that is the reason to keep it small.
>
> ```
> use UserAppClass;
>
> my UserAppClass $user-app .= new;
> exit($user-app.run);
> ```
>
> Well, you can’t get smaller than this …, or maybe use this one-liner; `exit(UserAppClass.new.run)`.
>
> The rest of the code is defined in the UserAppClass.

Very good.

1. Now, our program needs to accept arguments. `sub MAIN` does parsing arguments and generating `$*USAGE` gratis, so we would utilize `sub MAIN`.
   We put `sub MAIN` into a `use`d by `.raku` program `.rakumod` but we get the `.raku` program ignorant of the arguments. And `sub MAIN` is not executed when in a module.
   We put `sub MAIN` into the `.raku` program so that it understands arguments but it is no longer small.
2. Furthermore, embedded `POD` for the program is probably expected to reside in the `.raku` program.
   Put `POD` into a `use`d by `.raku` program `.rakumod` and we get the `POD` somewhat hidden.
   Put `POD` into the `.raku` program and again it is no longer small.
3. Also, are there any naming conventions for such an approach?
   Say, you have a program `Report when your coffee is ready`. Its `sub MAIN` is in `coffee-ready.raku`, and you `use` a `QueryCoffeeMachine.rakumod`.
   You change the layout of your files and now for the same program `Report when your coffee is ready` you have a `coffee-ready.raku` launcher, a `coffee-ready.MAIN.rakumod` with `sub MAIN`'s functionality in it and a `QueryCoffeeMachine.rakumod`.
   I believe `QueryCoffeeMachine.rakumod` stays intact,
   I feel `coffee-ready.raku` should also keep the name despite changing its contents
   but how should `coffee-ready.MAIN.rakumod` be named?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> > Anyways, before running, the compiled *modules* are saved into `.precomp` directories *but not the program*.

Aiui someone *could* extend precompilation to the main program file, but it's a low priority for core devs given that one can work around it with solutions like the following:

> 1. ... `sub MAIN` is not executed when in a module.

If you export/import it into the main program, the module's `MAIN` will execute when you run the main program:

```
# MAIN.rakumod
our sub MAIN (Int $int-arg, Str $str-arg) { $int-arg }

# main.raku
use lib '.';
use MAIN;
```

> 1. ... we get the `.raku` program ignorant of the arguments

If you `wrap` the imported `MAIN` in the main program, you will know the arguments:

```
# main.raku
use lib '.';
use MAIN;
&MAIN.wrap: -> |args { say args; callsame }
```

(If the args passed at the CLI don't match the signature of the `MAIN` sub imported from the `MAIN` module, then the usage message is displayed. Otherwise the wrapper in `main.raku` gets called and can do what it wishes with the passed args, and decide how it will call the imported `MAIN`.)

(I lifted this solution from [Can I capture the returned value of a routine used in RUN-MAIN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58941051/can-i-capture-the-returned-value-of-a-routine-used-in-run-main).)

> 2. Put POD into a ... `.rakumod` and we get the POD somewhat hidden.

I don't know of an existing way to avoid that. (Perhaps checkout [Access POD from another Raku file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50990701/access-pod-from-another-perl-6-file) for how to at least get access to POD in another file.)

Perhaps a new question narrowly focused on just that aspect is in order?

> 3. how should `.MAIN.rakumod` be named?

If it were me, off the top of my head, I might have a `Coffee-Ready` folder, and then within that, a `coffee-ready.raku`, a `MAIN.rakumod`, and a `QueryCoffeeMachine.rakumod`.